# Why does this a tag not work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I have this navbar but for some reason the `<a>` doesn't update the URL to the new address. I have try to give the `<a>` a `z-index 999;` but that still doesn't work.

its a one page site as you see I use # to get the browser jump to the right position.

No I have not a .htaccess file, the code you see is all I have

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar col-md-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="fa-microphone"></div><label>Bit-meeting</label>
        </div>

        <ul class="hidden-xs desktop-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#Forside">Forside</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#Om">Om</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#Plan">Plan</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#Talere">Talere</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#Billetter">Billetter</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#Blog">blog</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-border" href="#Kontakt">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**SCSS**

```
.navbar {
    height: $navbar;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $red;
    z-index: 19;
    background-color: white;

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 15px;

    .logo {
        margin-left: 15px;
        display: flex;
        line-height: $navbar;
        text-indent: 5px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        position: absolute;
        div {
            text-indent: 0px;
            color: black;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            background-color: #ED1C24;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            font-size: 2rem;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 60px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    }

    .desktop-menu {
        float: right;

        li {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-flex;

            a {
                padding: 0px 10px;
                line-height: $navbar;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                height: $navbar;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;

                &:hover {
                    background-color: $red;
                    color: white;
                }
            }

            .btn {
                line-height: 38px;
                height: 40px;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

A tag not work at all, even outside the nav.
*(No, I don't have more style for the ul, li and a then that you can see)*

Comment: Are there any elements in the body with the div id's in the navbar?

Comment: Nope this is the only one @Maxxxie

Comment: The SCSS won't change whether or not a link works. Try adding elements with the same id's in the header. If you're still having problems with that, just post the code, and we can work out a solution from there.

Comment: there is nothing to work for your "a-tag" without content using your anchors (for example id="Kontakt").... it should work well with content using the anchors.. so whats your issue?

Comment: @J.Sadi The issue is that even if I add a `<div id="Kontakt">` the `<a>` still doesn't change the url to example.com/index.php#Kontakt

Comment: Can you provide Snippet with this issue?

Comment: did i solved your issue? or why is there no more repsonse? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Change the showen URL by using anchors, you have to use javascript.

**For Example:**

JS:

```
function changeURL(key){
    history.replaceState({}, "", key);
}
```

And your Link:

```
<a href="#Forside" onClick="changeURL(this.href)">Forside</a>
```